# Some of the faces on my model are invisible

Tags: modeling

[image][image]

I've been having trouble with my exported model. I'm making some from Garry's Mod, when I finally compile my .mdl for it I'm greeted with this. I've tried flipping the normals and recalculating the outside and inside and so far it hasn't worked. The top-most photo is how it should appear, and the bottom on is the exported result. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but we have no idea what "Garry's Mod" refers to so there's no way we can even guess what the problem is, especially as you haven't shown any images of Blender's interface or shared you Blend file! You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page and use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu to create an image of Blender's screen then edit your question and add the image(s) into it

Comment: Hello, I have amended my question and provided the requested blend file. Garry's mod is a popular sand box game that uses .mdl model files. The way it works is that the models are Exported from blender as .smd files, these are created using the addon 'blender source tools' from there, they are converted to the mdl file type using a program called 'crowbar' along side a physics and value properties file known as a .qc file. Here is a link to the aforementioned program: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Crowbar Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to look at your file tomorrow as it's 12:45am here. The addon and external programs that you're talking about have nothing to do with Blender so are off-topic here. We can look at your Blend file and see if there are any obvious problems with it but once you export from Blender using a third-party addon and then use external software I'm afraid you're on your own and will have to get support from valvesoftware.

Comment: Had a very quick look and you'll need to pack your material images into the Blend file via File > External Data > Pack Resources and upload again before we can help.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so and replaced the previous file. I don't wish to trouble you further with this problem, so please don't feel like a follow-up post is necessary if you can't find anything. I will be trying to get into contact with the creators of the 'Crowbar' program to see if they can't be of some assistance.

Comment: Hi @Gooday welcome to BSE. I took a look at your file and it looks fine. But it does have overlapping duplicate vertices.  Go `tab` into *Edit Mode* and select all with `A` and press `M` > *Merge By Distance* which removes 38,376 vertices. then select all and press `Shift+N` to recalculate normals. https://snipboard.io/aw9DLQ.jpg If this does not resolve it then it is most likely a bug and bugs are unfortunately off-topic on this site. Here's the rendered result https://snipboard.io/1wNryL.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inverted Face Normals. To see them, enable *Face Orientation* under [`Viewport Overlays`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html). Faces should be blue for correct outward-pointing Face Normals. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate face normals outside. You also have overlapping duplicate vertices. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* to remove 38,376 overlapping vertices.

[image]

Comment: That's fixed it! Thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it got fixed!

Comment: Yep. Note that just trying recalculating the normals on its own won't fix the problem. Best to use Merge by Distance first although the shading will look very odd until you've recalculated the normals too!  You won't need to wake up the crowbar folks now! :^)